# Solve for Joint Distribution Function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, integral-equations

I wish to find a joint PDF $h(p,b) $or CDF $H(p,b)$, given the following expression:

$(1-L) r \int _0^r\int _0^{\frac{p}{1-L}}h(p,b)dbdp-  r L \int _0^r\int _0^{\frac{p-r}{1-L}+\frac{r}{L}}h(p,b)dbdp=0,$

where $0<L<1/2$ and $1/2<L<1$ and $r>0$ is some constaant.  I naively tried the simple

```
Solve[{Integrate[h[p, b], {p, 0, r}, {b, 0, (p/(1 - L))}] (1 - L) r - Integrate[h[p, b], {p, 0, r}, {b, 0, (1/(1 - L)) (p - r) + (r/L)}] L r == 0 }, h[p, b]]
```

and of course it "does not work" since I receive the following answer

```
{{h[p, b] -> 0}}.
```

This answer is surely incorrect.  Ideally, I should get some joint probability distribution function of the two variables $p$ and $b$.  Also note that probably there are two solutions: one for $0<L1/2$ and the other for $1/2<L<1$ (so $l=1/2$ is excluded).

Comment: Have you tried converting this to a differential equation?

Comment: @J.M. If you mean to take partial derivatives with respect o $p$ and $b$, technically I can do that.  But for the problem I am trying to solve, I cannot do that.

Comment: I suspect that there must be more than one solution depending on if you need a joint distribution that satisfies the condition for all $L$ in $0<L<1$ and for all $r>0$ or just particular values of $L$ and $r$.  For example, suppose $L=1/2$.  Then any value of $r>0$ satisfies your condition for any legitimate $h[p,b]$.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Thanks for the answer.  My apologies, for I forgot to add additional information on $L$. I will make necessary changes in the original question

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an extended comment.  I wonder if rather than first going after a general solution that you try some specific joint probability density functions and observe what values of $L$ and $r$ satisfy your condition.

For example, consider $p$ and $b$ having independent exponential distributions:

```
f = (1 - L)*r*Integrate[Exp[-p]*Exp[-b], {p, 0, r}, {b, 0, p/(1 - L)}] – 
  L*r*Integrate[Exp[-p]*Exp[-b], {p, 0, r}, {b, 0, (p - r)/(1 - L) + r/L}]
```

A contour plot shows the solutions for `f==0`:

```
ContourPlot[f == 0, {L, 0.000001, 0.4}, {r, 0.000001, 10}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Map[Style[#, Bold, Large, Italic] &, {"L", "r"}]]
```

[image: Contour plot]

I don’t think there are any solutions for $0.5 < L < 1$ for this particular joint density function.  In fact other than the solution where $L=0.5$, there doesn’t appear to be any combinations of $L$ and $r$ with $L>0.38198$ that can satisfy the condition.